# How to display time of day on a ggplot axis after using SQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP()?

Tags: mysql, r, ggplot2

I am working with data returned by a query similar to this:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 300 AS period, COUNT(*) as count from tbl
GROUP BY UNIX_TIMESTAMP(timestamp) DIV 300
```

which is grouping the counts into 5 minute intervals and is then imported into R and looks like this:

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(period = seq(5391360, 5391647), count = rpois(288, 4))
head(mydata)
##     period count
## 1 5391360     3
## 2 5391361     3
## 3 5391362     4
## 4 5391363     7
## 5 5391364     2
## 6 5391365     7
```

I then plot them like this:

I would now like to plot this with ggplot, where the x axis shows the actual time starting in hourly intervals, 01:00, 02:00 03:00 etc. I have been doing this by piping the data into:

```
ggplot(aes(y = count, x = period)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
  ggtitle("5 min counts") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(lineheight=.8, face="bold", hjust = 0.5), 
        axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 1, hjust = 1))
```

which produces this:
[image]

However, as mentioned above I would like the x axis to have hourly labels: 01:00, 02:00 etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this solution, first I create a vector of datetime values. The vector `df1$period` is multiplied by 300 and coerced to class `"POSIXct`. Then the hours and minutes are kept.

```
period <- as.POSIXct(df1$period*300, origin = "1970-01-01")
period <- format(period, "%H:%M")

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = data.frame(period, count = df1$count),
       mapping = aes(period, count)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

---

To have a plot by hour, instead of keeping the hours and minutes, use `format` to keep the hours only. But then `aggregate` the counts by hour.

```
set.seed(1)
mydata <- data.frame(period = seq(5391360, 5391647), count = rpois(288, 4))

mydata$hour <- as.POSIXct(mydata$period*300, origin = "1970-01-01")
mydata$hour <- format(mydata$hour, "%H")
agg <- aggregate(count ~ hour, mydata, sum)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(data = agg, aes(hour, count)) +
  geom_col(position = position_dodge())
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you (+1). However I need to have the x axis labels at 1 hour intervals (because I have 24 hours of data)

Comment: I have updated the question with a more realistic dataset.

Comment: @JoeKing Answer updated, see now if it's what you want.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you !